# Why am I getting a recordnotfound error when trying to access an instance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user profile controller called "userinfo" and it's corresponding view. The userinfo index is the root path. In the homepage(which is the userinfo index), I have a link that takes you to the user profile page. It is giving me this error when I go to the home page:[image]

My routes are:[image]
My userinfos_controller:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
      @userinfors = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def show
        @myvideo = Video.last
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to userinfo_path
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

and my view is:

```
 <%= link_to 'profile', userinfors_path(@userinfors) %>
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :userinfos do
    resources :videos
  end
  resources :pages
  get '/application/decide' => 'application#decide'
  root 'userinfos#index'
  get '/userinfos/:id', to: 'userinfos#show', as: 'userinfors'
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, there are multiple errors and you are not following conventions of rails, `index` is not for what you have used.
`Index` is used to list all the users and `show` for a particular one with `id` passed in `params`.

Your index path is, as you can see, `/userinfos` which is correct and it doesn't have any `id` with it but you are trying to find `user` with `params[:id]` which is `nil` and hence the error.

Lets try out this:

```
def index
  @userinfors = Userinfo.all #pagination is recommended
end
```

In your index view,

```
<% @userinfors.each do |userinfor| %>
  <%= link_to "#{userinfor.name}'s profile", userinfo_path(userinfor) %>
<% end %>
```

It should work now.

Please read [`routing`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) and [`action controller`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) to get the idea and understand the ***magic*** behind **rails routing** and **mvc** architecture..

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to use a shortcut because I didn't want to create associations between different controllers. But yeah, your ways works.

Comment: You can definitely manipulate rails as per your needs but that needs understanding of standard approach..anyway, glad it helped.. :)